# Obtaining the per-process CPU-time clock of another process in Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

How to check whether linux kernel support obtaining the per-process CPU-time clock of another process?

In Detail :

clock_getcpuclockid() returns EPERM error if The caller does not have permission to access the CPU-time clock of the process specified by pid.  (Specified as  an optional error in POSIX.1-2001; does not occur on Linux unless the kernel does not support obtaining the per-process CPU-time clock of another process.)

So, my question is how to check whether linux kernel support obtaining the per-process CPU-time clock of another process? In other words how can I make clock_getcpuclockid() to fail with return value EPERM?

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel supports this if `clock_getcpuclockid()` succeeds.

Comment: yes I know but if I want to disable the support how can I do that. In other words how can I make clock_getcpuclockid() to fail with return value EPERM?

Comment: This is not what you asked in the question; and it's not possible without changing the kernel.